# Broken aloe vera

Tags: aloe

My friends"aloe vera" plant broke in half, while transporting it. Can the top part of it be saved? It's in water right now but I don't think that's the way to do it.

Comment: Nope, not for a desert plant. Dry out the wounds 1-2 days, then plant and place in sun.